# How to use quote and \" inside the aspx page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using custom control in aspx and i need to use custom property in my aspx control.The custom property string doesn't working fine in aspx page. I can't use quotes and \" inside the custom property string.

My code is like this

```
<asp:customControl  customProperty="<div><span data-bind=\"text: &quot;Change : &quot; + viewModel.Change() + &quot; %&quot;\"></span></div>">
```

How can i use the quotes and \" in aspx page.

Any suggestion should be appreciated.!

Thanks,
KarthiK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, with single quotes instead:

```
<asp:customControl  customProperty="<div><span data-bind='text: \&quot;Change : \&quot; + viewModel.Change() + \&quot;%\&quot;'></span></div>"></asp:customControl>
```

If the outer has double quotes, you can use single quotes in the value.

Comment: Was that no good? Show me the desired html output and I will update it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i have tried what you said, i got this string output in server side "<div><span data-bind='text: "Change : " + viewModel.Change() + " %"'></span></div>"  while passing this to client side again am getting error, so i changed your code like this
"<div><span data-bind='text: \&quot;Change : \&quot; + viewModel.Change() + \&quot;%\&quot;'></span></div>", this works fine for me :)